# Small caps with CMSS?

Tags: fonts, small-caps, sans-serif, computer-modern

How can I use small caps with the CMSS font?
When trying to set `fontshape` to "sc" I get a serif font or just no change (if I use `fonthshape`alone):

result of example below:
[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{\fontfamily{#1}\fontseries{#2}\fontshape{#3}\selectfont}

\newcommand{\Ena}[1]{{\changefont{cmss}{m}{sc}#1}} %Eigennamen
\newcommand{\Enb}[1]{{\fontshape{sc}#1}} %Eigennamen


\begin{document}

\changefont{cmss}{m}{n} 
Normal Text and \Ena{Text with Small Caps} or \Enb{Text with Small Caps}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know neither the cmss nor lmss family has a small caps font.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Is it unusual (or typographically "bad") to use small caps with Sans Serif fonts or what is the reason that they just don't exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think CMSS simply doesn't have smallcaps; not very many sans-serif fonts do. Somebody with the appropriate MetaFONT-Fu could probably make some, either for Computer Modern or for Latin Modern.

Comment: Is it unusual (or typographically "bad") to use small caps with Sans Serif fonts or what is the reason that they just don't exist?

Comment: Small caps are most often used in normal paragraph text when there are lots of initials being used, e.g. "The computer system for the WTO was supplied by IBM." Since most paragraph text is set with serif fonts, there's less of a need for sans-serif fonts with small caps. In addition, small caps are usually only provided in "professional" typefaces since the letters actually have to be redesigned and not just scaled down. There's nothing "bad" about using them, however.

Comment: @beerbajay I know font designers who would vehemently disagree with the claim that there is nothing 'bad' about such designs ;).

Comment: @cfr It's generally considered "bad" to typeset paragraphs with sans-serif fonts, but that's exactly what we're doing almost everywhere on the web. The argument for small caps must hold for both serif and sans- text once you've already taken the step of setting paragraphs in sans-?

Comment: @beerbajay Maybe. I'm not sure. Since I tend to use small-caps for section headings and those are often set in sans-serif, that hadn't occurred to me. [I use serif small-caps - not sans - but I'm just thinking about it.] I think you'd have to ask the font designers. (But they are designing partly for the web so I wonder if there is a further objection.)

Answer (score 2):

There are some other fonts with Small Caps:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{libertine}
\newcommand\Ena[1]{{\sffamily\scshape#1}}
\newcommand\Enb[1]{{\scshape#1}}
\begin{document}
Normal Text and \Ena{Text with Small Caps} or 

\Enb{Text with Small Caps}      
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be mine is not a good work around, but was enough for me as a patch for the `lettrine` package. I patched it with `\scalebox` and writing in capital letters:

```
...
\newcommand{\Enc}[1]{\scalebox{0.8}{#1}}
...
Normal Text and \Ena{Text with Small Caps} or \Enb{Text with Small Caps} or  T\Enb{EXT WITH SMALL CAPS}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a version of computer modern with small caps in the `sansmathfonts` package.  You can use it follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[notmath]{sansmathfonts}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\textsc{Is This Better Than Fake Small Caps?}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

the above answer is not working for me

my alternative: `\textsc{\textsf{Test}}` works fine :D

Another alternative are super fonts: `\usepackage{type1ec}`

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look at the guidance on how to use the site. I'm not clear which answer doesn't work for you, but that isn't really an answer. Also, the commands you suggest will not work fine for the OP. If they work for you, you're using something other than CM/LM.  Neither will `type1ec` solve the problem, but I'm interested in the mention as I'd never come across this before.